# How to Ignore url http:// with <?php echo $_GET['i']; ?>

Tags: php

example

im using this code `<?php echo $_GET['i']; ?` like this example

```
www.url.com/<?php echo $_GET['i']; ?>
```

users submit links like http://stackoverflow.com and end up showing www.url.com/http://stackoverflow.com

so i want to be able to Ignore the "http://" only display

www.url.com/stackoverflow.com

Comment: there is a link on $_GET['i']

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Non-persistent

Comment: 'i' is a very poor index name.

Answer (score 1):

ok, try this,

```
$uri = preg_replace("/^(http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)$/", "", $_GET[i]);
echo $uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix:

```
<?php echo str_replace('http://', '', $_GET['i']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$GET = $_GET['i'];
$remove = array("http://", "https://");
$redirect = str_replace($remove, "", $GET);
?>

www.url.com/<?php echo $redirect; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a replace as others have said, you should use `urlencode()` to avoid an [XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

```
echo urlencode(str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $_GET['i']));
```